# Field interaction betweeen two point charges?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames

[SOLVED]

Consider two particles *A* and *B* having equal charges and placed at some distance. The particle *A* is slightly displaced towards  *B*.

So,

Does the EM force on  *B* increase(+/-)  **as soon as** the particle  *A* is displaced?

Does the EM force on  *A* increase(+/-) **as soon as** it is displaced?

The first question is a straight no, since the field don't interact instantaneously, however what about the second question?

P.S: This from the short answer section of the chapter 29 from Concepts of Physics (Part 2) H.C.Verma (ISBN-13: 978-8177092325)

Comment: @Qmechanic I did understand electromagnetism as the particle is displaced and speed-of-light as the time lag will be t = r/c(distance/speed) but Why reference frame?? special relativity??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the answer to the second question is affirmative, as the field already exists in the point where A is displaced to.